# How to set user identity

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'd like to report analytics using Firebase from different platforms (same user can have multiple desktop/mobile devices).

Is there a way to set user identity so all events from all devices will be aggregated into same unique user?

I only see a way to report user properties in documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/properties

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [setUserID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/interface_f_i_r_analytics.html#a9e70957b5c5f24a25e534e5def1ef432) API allows you to associate a user identity with the app-instance.

Comment: How is that presented or used in the Firebase Analytics consol. I could not see that you could filter user

Comment: when user sign out, what is best to put in the ´setUserId()´. Until a new or same user sign in again is it ok to put ´null´?

Answer (score 0):

In case of logout you have to set user id to empty string `setUserID("")` , because users still being tracked if `.setUserID(null)` doesn't do the trick